# spring maven active profile

Tags: spring, maven, profile

I am trying to run the Spring application from the server.

What is the difference between:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

and

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev
```

Tnx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that the second property, `spring-boot.run.profiles`, comes from the Spring Boot Maven plugin which allows you to define profiles in your `pom.xml`, while `spring.profiles.active` comes from spring and can be used without any plugin, but in the end, they can do the same thing.